# Keycloak - merge users with same email

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, identity

I am trying to allow users log in with **multiple social media identity providers but have them linked to one email** using Keycloak 8.0.1. Logging in for each one IDP works.

When I try to first login with google this works. When I then log in with facebook, I am getting 
`KC-SERVICES0013: Failed authentication: org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationFlowException`. Futher in the log I see a `IDENTITY_PROVIDER_FIRST_LOGIN_ERROR`. The message is  I am just using the default authentication flows - First Broker login as *First Login Flow* and empty as *Post Login Flow*.

I assume the Authentication flow needs to be adjusted somehow?
Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: As I do not use user federation, I only can answer your Question for adjusting Auth flows. Thats possible. Have a look at: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_authentication-flows

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm trying the exact same thing now?